# NSPredicate and Core Data multi-table queries

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an SQL command that would be pretty trivial to construct with normal SQL, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting it working with Core Data.

I have 3 Entities; Item, Folder and Group. An Item is in a Folder and a Folder is in a Group. A folder is made unique through both the folder name and the group name. An item just stores a folder name, whilst a folder stores a folder name and a group name.

The SQL command in question is roughly this: `SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE Item.folderName = folderName AND Folder.folderName = Item.folderName AND Folder.groupName = groupName;`

(and yes, I know I don't get a specific attribute with CoreData, I was just doing it for the example)

The problem arises when I do the `Folder.folderName = Item.folderName AND Folder.groupName = groupName` part. I can't figure out how to represent this as a predicate.

I should note that I have a relationship between Item and Folder as well as a relationship between Folder and Group.

EDIT:

This is the setup for my data model:

[image: Data Setup]

This is the code I'm now using to make a request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavouriteItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[request setEntity:entity];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderName = %@ AND folderRelationship.groupName = %@", self.folderName, self.groupName];

NSError *fetchError;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
```

Comment: Is item.folderName the name of its containing folder and the same as item.folder.folderName?

Comment: If you have relationships why are you not using them?

Comment: @Willeke, yes. quellish, because I don't know how and I was confused by the documentation available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you want to fetch all the items in a specific folder (i.e., you want all items with a given folderName and groupName... which uniquely identifies a specific folder).

Since you say you already have relationships, I will assume they are setup with inverse relationships.

Further, I will assume that an Item has a to-one relationship named "folder" which is the folder that item is in.  The folder will have a to-many relationship "items" for the items in that folder.

Thus, the following would be one of many ways to accomplish what you want.

```
- (NSSet*)getItemsForFolderName:(NSString*)folderName
                      groupName:(NSString*)groupName
                          inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
                          error:(NSError**)error {
    NSSet *result = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Folder"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderName = %@ AND groupName = %@", folderName, groupName];
    fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"items"];
    NSArray *folders = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
    if (folders) {
        result = [[folders firstObject] items];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also simply fetch the items.  As for which is best, it depends on how you have your attributes indexed, and what type of other fetching you are doing.

```
- (NSArray*)getItemsForFolderName:(NSString*)folderName
                        groupName:(NSString*)groupName
                            inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
                            error:(NSError**)error {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderName = %@ AND folder.groupName = %@", folderName, groupName];
    return [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
}
```

**EDIT**

JamEngulfer221, I was pretty sure these examples would work, but since you said they didn't even after I pointed out the mistake in your post, I thought I'd hack up a quick project and test... I'm old, and sometimes forget stuff...

So, I hacked up a test, with the following code.

First, create the model...

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)makeModel {
    NSEntityDescription *group = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    group.name = @"Group";
    NSAttributeDescription *groupName = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    groupName.name = @"groupName";
    groupName.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    NSEntityDescription *folder = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    folder.name = @"Folder";
    NSAttributeDescription *folderName = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    folderName.name = @"folderName";
    folderName.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    NSEntityDescription *item = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    item.name = @"Item";
    NSAttributeDescription *itemName = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    itemName.name = @"itemName";
    itemName.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    NSRelationshipDescription *folderToGroupRelationship = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
    NSRelationshipDescription *groupToFoldersRelationship = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];

    groupToFoldersRelationship.name = @"folders";
    groupToFoldersRelationship.destinationEntity = folder;
    groupToFoldersRelationship.minCount = 0;
    groupToFoldersRelationship.maxCount = 0;
    groupToFoldersRelationship.deleteRule = NSCascadeDeleteRule;
    groupToFoldersRelationship.inverseRelationship = folderToGroupRelationship;

    folderToGroupRelationship.name = @"group";
    folderToGroupRelationship.destinationEntity = group;
    folderToGroupRelationship.minCount = 0;
    folderToGroupRelationship.maxCount = 1;
    folderToGroupRelationship.deleteRule = NSNullifyDeleteRule;
    folderToGroupRelationship.inverseRelationship = groupToFoldersRelationship;

    NSRelationshipDescription *folderToItemsRelationship = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];
    NSRelationshipDescription *itemToFolderRelationship = [[NSRelationshipDescription alloc] init];

    folderToItemsRelationship.name = @"items";
    folderToItemsRelationship.destinationEntity = item;
    folderToItemsRelationship.minCount = 0;
    folderToItemsRelationship.maxCount = 0;
    folderToItemsRelationship.deleteRule = NSCascadeDeleteRule;
    folderToItemsRelationship.inverseRelationship = itemToFolderRelationship;

    itemToFolderRelationship.name = @"folder";
    itemToFolderRelationship.destinationEntity = folder;
    itemToFolderRelationship.minCount = 0;
    itemToFolderRelationship.maxCount = 1;
    itemToFolderRelationship.deleteRule = NSNullifyDeleteRule;
    itemToFolderRelationship.inverseRelationship = folderToItemsRelationship;

    group.properties = @[groupName, groupToFoldersRelationship];
    folder.properties = @[folderName, groupName, folderToGroupRelationship, folderToItemsRelationship];
    item.properties = @[itemName, folderName, itemToFolderRelationship];

    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
    model.entities = @[group, folder, item];
    return model;
}
```

And the search method...

```
- (NSArray*)getItemsForFolderName:(NSString*)folderName
                        groupName:(NSString*)groupName
                            inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
                            error:(NSError**)error {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folderName = %@ AND folder.groupName = %@", folderName, groupName];
    return [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
}
```

And the test...

```
- (void)testBlarg {
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self makeModel];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

    for (int g = 0; g < 10; ++g) {
        NSManagedObject *group = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        NSString *groupName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Group %02d", g];
        [group setValue:groupName forKey:@"groupName"];
        for (int f = 0; f < 10; ++f) {
            NSManagedObject *folder = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            NSString *folderName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Folder %02d", f];
            [folder setValue:folderName forKey:@"folderName"];
            [folder setValue:groupName forKey:@"groupName"];
            [folder setValue:group forKey:@"group"];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                NSManagedObject *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                NSString *itemName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %02d (%@;%@)", i, folderName, groupName];
                [item setValue:itemName forKey:@"itemName"];
                [item setValue:folderName forKey:@"folderName"];
                [item setValue:folder forKey:@"folder"];
            }
        }
    }
    [moc save:NULL];
    [moc reset];

    NSString *folderName = @"Folder 04";
    NSString *groupName = @"Group 02";
    NSArray *items = [self getItemsForFolderName:folderName groupName:groupName inMOC:moc error:NULL];
    items = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES]]];
    XCTAssertEqual(10, items.count);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        NSManagedObject *object = items[i];
        NSString *expectedItemName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %02d (%@;%@)", i, folderName, groupName];
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedItemName, [object valueForKey:@"itemName"]);
        NSManagedObject *folder = [object valueForKey:@"folder"];
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(folderName, [folder valueForKey:@"folderName"]);
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(groupName, [folder valueForKey:@"groupName"]);
        NSManagedObject *group = [folder valueForKey:@"group"];
        XCTAssertEqualObjects(groupName, [group valueForKey:@"groupName"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your second option and it didn't seem to work. I've got the relationships set up, but when I make the request I get 0 results.

Comment: Then maybe you don't have your relationships setup like you think you do ;-)  Why don't you post screenshots of your model details and the exact code you used to make the query (note the assumptions I made).

Comment: Ok, I updated the original post with an image and my code. Hope that helps

Comment: Your predicate is wrong.  The relationship is named "folderRelationship" but that just accesses the relationship itself.  You need to compare using the groupName property.  Copy/paste my example, and change the relationship name and it should work -- or just add ".groupName" to your relationship.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 One more thing...  you should not think of core data in terms of SQL select commands.  You should think of your model as objects and relationships.  Figure out how you want to access your data, and then design your object graph accordingly.

Comment: I was going to mention in my original post that I know that Core Data isn't just a wrapper for SQL and that I gave an SQL command because it communicated what I was trying to do best, but I thought that would be obvious and omitted it. Also, I accidentally copied my code snippet halfway through editing it, so the one in the original post is wrong. It should just be a copy of yours with the correct relationship name.

Comment: I'm sorry, yeah your solution fixed my problem. I made a mistake and had the folder name set incorrectly.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221- Good.  Now that you understand how this works, you should probably redesign your model layout.  Core data models rarely are the same as standard SQL models.  See Mundi's post for one example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data model setup is flawed, causing this confusion. Actually, your problem is quite simple.

First, if an item is assigned to a folder *you do not need to store the folder name* - that would be redundant and thus unnecessary information. The same applies to folders and group names.

Second, the parent folder should be a reflexive relationship to the same entity, not an attribute.

All entities should just have a `name` attribute and these relationships (note the intuitive non-technical relationship names):

```
Group (folders)     <------>> (group) Folder (items) <------->> (folder) Item
Folder (subFolders) <------>> (parentFolder) Folder
```

The predicate is now trivial:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"folder.name = %@ && folder.group.name = %@", folderName, groupName]
```